# What is the prior mu in Heterogeneous Graph Transformer?

Tags: class-imbalance, transformer, attention-mechanism, graph-neural-network, gnn

I am reading https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.01332.pdf and do not understand what the prior (\mu) is supposed to be. I also found their implementation on github, but it is still not clear to me. For context: The model operates on graphs where tau(s) phi(e) tau(t) is the "meta"-edgetype between the class of nodes s and t.

I am thinking it is some sort of edge count, e.g. the amount found in the training data, for each metaedge type. Is this correct?

[image]

[image]